# python split array into runs/sequences - preferably numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can i split it into sequences/runs/subsequent-numbers, if the run is no longer than 3?

Having an array as follows

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

My expected output would be the following arrays:

1. `[1, 2, 3]`
2. `[5]`
3. `[9, 10]`
4. `[16, 17, 18]`
5. `[19]`

e.g. `[[1, 2, 3], [5], [9, 10], [16, 17, 18], [19]]`

If it is a run of length 8 e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` i would like to get `8 / 3 + 1 = 2` lists:

1. `[1, 2, 3]`
2. `[4, 5, 6]`
3. `[7, 8]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name your current list, `x` and the new list of output, `new_list`, you can try (untested and assumes no repeat values in original list)

```
k = 0
new_list = [[]]
for i in range(len(x) - 1):
    if x[i] not in new_list[max(k - 1, 0)]:
        new_list[k].append(x[i])
        for j in range(i + 1, len(x)):    
            if x[j] - x[i] == j - i and x[j] not in new_list[k]:
               new_list[k].append(x[j])
        k += 1
        new_list.append([])

new_list = [x for x in new_list if x != []] # gets rid of empty list at the end
```

Comment: IMHO i think on line 3 it it should be `range(len(x))` instead of `range(len(x) - 1)`... Look for example for: `x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version that uses `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain
def split_list(mylist):
    """Function to do the initial split"""
    # calculate differences
    d = np.diff(mylist)
    # when the differences are not 1 save that location
    # we need a +1 to get make up for the lost element
    breaks = list(np.arange(len(mylist) - 1)[d != 1] + 1)
    slices = zip([0] + breaks, breaks + [len(mylist)])
    # slice up the list
    int_list = [mylist[a:b] for a, b in slices]
    # chop up long sequences
    chopped = [chop(l) for l in int_list]
    # flatten the list once
    return list(chain.from_iterable(chopped))

def chop(sublist, max_len=3):
    """Chops a list into chunks of length max_len"""
    breaks = list(range(0, len(sublist), max_len))
    slices = zip(breaks, breaks[1:] + [len(sublist)])
    return [sublist[a:b] for a, b in slices]
```

Running this on the list's given:

```
>>> split_list([1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19])
[[1, 2, 3], [5], [9, 10], [16, 17, 18], [19]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
def split_list(list, sub_list_size = 3):
    sublists = []

    for i in range(0, len(list), sub_list_size):
        start = i
        end = i + sub_list_size
        sublists.append(list[start:end])

    return sublists


# your list
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9, 10, 11]

# your output
sublists = split_list(mylist)

print(sublists)
```

produces the following output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

The syntax `list[start:end]` will work even if `end` it is larger than the actual list size.

Hope this helps